# How to solve error "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql

I want to create a customers table with foreign key relations but when I execute the query I'm getting an error like this:

> (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customerName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactLastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactFirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `salesRepEmployeeNumber` int(11),
  `creditLimit` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerNumber`),
  KEY `salesRepEmployeeNumber` (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: 'How to solve' - work through the conditions required for your version of mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Please add table employees.

Answer (score 0):

Check if:

- 'employeeNumber' column should have an index.
- 'salesRepEmployeeNumber' and 'employeeNumber' have same type and
  length.

Comment: Your first point is incorrect. It is only necessary that the `employeeNumber` column has an index on it, not that it is the primary key. See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Ohh yeah!! I missed it. Thanks :)

Comment: So you should correct your answer... used the `edit` link...

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check if value exist with "salesRepEmployeeNumber" which is not available in salesRepEmployeeNumber table. Try to remove all "salesRepEmployeeNumber". Check all reference ids before making Foreign Key relation.

Comment: i tried this also but didn't worked